# What is the difference between the yellow and blue movement alerts?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Sometimes I see a yellow alert for alien movement or something, what does this mean and how is it different from the usual blue movement?

Example below of "yellow" alert

[image]

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The linked question pre-dates "Enemy Within", which is when the Meld (and thus the artifact presented in this question) was added to the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Holographic Orange Lines** (as in your screenshot) point to undiscovered Meld containers and are always the same sound.

The **Soundwave-y Lines** point to undiscovered Pods (and are different sounds based on the makeup of the pod)

Comment: Ah! I play with sound off and went into Enemy Within as part of long war, thanks!